# ANDY Error Unable to Launch VM Process

Tags: android, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device, haxm

When I start up my andyroid I get this error

Andy Error

Unable to launch VM Process: The virtual machine 'andy' has terminated
unexpectedly during start up with

```html
1a64.1a20: Log file opened: 4.3.28r100309 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000028 g_uNtVerCombined=0x63258000
1a64.1a20: \SystemRoot\System32\ntdll.dll:
1a64.1a20:     CreationTime:    2015-04-14T19:07:42.947120400Z
1a64.1a20:     LastWriteTime:   2015-03-23T21:59:25.551884100Z
1a64.1a20:     ChangeTime:      2015-04-17T01:36:19.499612400Z
1a64.1a20:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1a64.1a20:     Size:            0x1a7540
1a64.1a20:     NT Headers:      0xd8
1a64.1a20:     Timestamp:       0x550f4336
1a64.1a20:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1a64.1a20:     Timestamp:       0x550f4336
1a64.1a20:     Image Version:   6.3
1a64.1a20:     SizeOfImage:     0x1ac000 (1753088)
1a64.1a20:     Resource Dir:    0x148000 LB 0x62450
1a64.1a20:     ProductName:     MicrosoftÂ® WindowsÂ® Operating System
1a64.1a20:     ProductVersion:  6.3.9600.17736
1a64.1a20:     FileVersion:     6.3.9600.17736 (winblue_r9.150322-1500)
1a64.1a20:     FileDescription: NT Layer DLL
1a64.1a20: \SystemRoot\System32\kernel32.dll:
1a64.1a20:     CreationTime:    2015-04-22T05:04:23.514770100Z
1a64.1a20:     LastWriteTime:   2014-10-29T04:09:24.572407200Z
1a64.1a20:     ChangeTime:      2015-04-25T05:52:10.862493500Z
1a64.1a20:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1a64.1a20:     Size:            0x13fc30
1a64.1a20:     NT Headers:      0xf8
1a64.1a20:     Timestamp:       0x545054ca
1a64.1a20:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1a64.1a20:     Timestamp:       0x545054ca
1a64.1a20:     Image Version:   6.3
1a64.1a20:     SizeOfImage:     0x13e000 (1302528)
1a64.1a20:     Resource Dir:    0x12e000 LB 0x518
1a64.1a20:     ProductName:     MicrosoftÂ® WindowsÂ® Operating System
1a64.1a20:     ProductVersion:  6.3.9600.17415
1a64.1a20:     FileVersion:     6.3.9600.17415 (winblue_r4.141028-1500)
1a64.1a20:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
1a64.1a20: \SystemRoot\System32\KernelBase.dll:
1a64.1a20:     CreationTime:    2015-04-22T05:06:28.303432700Z
1a64.1a20:     LastWriteTime:   2014-10-29T03:55:08.402989600Z
1a64.1a20:     ChangeTime:      2015-04-25T05:50:45.011248900Z
1a64.1a20:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1a64.1a20:     Size:            0x114a90
1a64.1a20:     NT Headers:      0xf0
1a64.1a20:     Timestamp:       0x54505737
1a64.1a20:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1a64.1a20:     Timestamp:       0x54505737
1a64.1a20:     Image Version:   6.3
1a64.1a20:     SizeOfImage:     0x115000 (1134592)
1a64.1a20:     Resource Dir:    0x110000 LB 0x3528
1a64.1a20:     ProductName:     MicrosoftÂ® WindowsÂ® Operating System
1a64.1a20:     ProductVersion:  6.3.9600.17415
1a64.1a20:     FileVersion:     6.3.9600.17415 (winblue_r4.141028-1500)
1a64.1a20:     FileDescription: Windows NT BASE API Client DLL
1a64.1a20: \SystemRoot\System32\apisetschema.dll:
1a64.1a20:     CreationTime:    2013-08-22T12:13:09.745625900Z
1a64.1a20:     LastWriteTime:   2013-08-22T12:35:12.091034400Z
1a64.1a20:     ChangeTime:      2015-01-22T23:40:03.392651800Z
1a64.1a20:     FileAttributes:  0x20
1a64.1a20:     Size:            0x11360
1a64.1a20:     NT Headers:      0xd0
1a64.1a20:     Timestamp:       0x52160049
1a64.1a20:     Machine:         0x8664 - amd64
1a64.1a20:     Timestamp:       0x52160049
1a64.1a20:     Image Version:   6.3
1a64.1a20:     SizeOfImage:     0x13000 (77824)
1a64.1a20:     Resource Dir:    0x11000 LB 0x3f8
1a64.1a20:     ProductName:     MicrosoftÂ® WindowsÂ® Operating System
1a64.1a20:     ProductVersion:  6.3.9600.16384
1a64.1a20:     FileVersion:     6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)
1a64.1a20:     FileDescription: ApiSet Schema DLL
1a64.1a20: supR3HardenedWinFindAdversaries: 0x0
1a64.1a20: Calling main()
1a64.1a20: SUPR3HardenedMain: pszProgName=VBoxHeadless fFlags=0x0
1a64.1a20: SUPR3HardenedMain: Respawn #1
1a64.1a20: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32
1a64.1a20: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\WinSxS
1a64.1a20: KnownDllPath: C:\Windows\system32
1a64.1a20: '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
1a64.1a20: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe)
1a64.1a20: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
1a64.1a20: supR3HardNtDisableThreadCreation: pvLdrInitThunk=00007ffcc3498eb0 pvNtTerminateThread=00007ffcc35116f0
1a64.1a20: supR3HardenedWinDoReSpawn(1): New child 1410.1a88 [kernel32].
1a64.1a20: supR3HardNtChildGatherData: PebBaseAddress=00007ff68328f000 cbPeb=0x388
1a64.1a20: supR3HardNtPuChFindNtdll: uNtDllParentAddr=00007ffcc3480000 uNtDllChildAddr=00007ffcc3480000
1a64.1a20: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: uLdrInitThunk=00007ffcc3498eb0
1a64.1a20: supR3HardenedWinSetupChildInit: Start child.
1a64.1a20: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor: Found expected request 0 (PurifyChildAndCloseHandles) after 0 ms.
1a64.1a20: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Startup delay kludge #1/0: 261 ms, 29 sleeps
1a64.1a20: supHardNtVpScanVirtualMemory: enmKind=CHILD_PURIFICATION
1a64.1a20:  *0000000000000000-ffffffffff56ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1a64.1a20:  *0000000000a90000-0000000000a6ffff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1a64.1a20:  *0000000000ab0000-0000000000aa0fff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1a64.1a20:   0000000000abf000-0000000000abdfff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1a64.1a20:  *0000000000ac0000-00000000009c3fff 0x0000/0x0004 0x0020000
1a64.1a20:   0000000000bbc000-0000000000bb8fff 0x0104/0x0004 0x0020000
1a64.1a20:   0000000000bbf000-0000000000bbdfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1a64.1a20:  *0000000000bc0000-0000000000bbbfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1a64.1a20:   0000000000bc4000-0000000000bb7fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1a64.1a20:  *0000000000bd0000-0000000000bcdfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1a64.1a20:   0000000000bd2000-ffffffff817c3fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1a64.1a20:  *000000007ffe0000-000000007ffdefff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0020000
1a64.1a20:   000000007ffe1000-000000007ffd1fff 0x0000/0x0002 0x0020000
1a64.1a20:   000000007fff0000-ffff800a7cd7ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1a64.1a20:  *00007ff683260000-00007ff68323cfff 0x0002/0x0002 0x0040000
1a64.1a20:   00007ff683283000-00007ff683278fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1a64.1a20:  *00007ff68328d000-00007ff68328afff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1a64.1a20:  *00007ff68328f000-00007ff68328dfff 0x0004/0x0004 0x0020000
1a64.1a20:   00007ff683290000-00007ff682d1ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1a64.1a20:  *00007ff683800000-00007ff683800fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff683801000-00007ff683885fff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff683886000-00007ff683886fff 0x0080/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff683887000-00007ff6838c4fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff6838c5000-00007ff6838c5fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff6838c6000-00007ff6838c6fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff6838c7000-00007ff6838c8fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff6838c9000-00007ff6838c9fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff6838ca000-00007ff6838cafff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff6838cb000-00007ff6838cefff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff6838cf000-00007ff683907fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe
1a64.1a20:   00007ff683908000-00007ff043d8ffff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1a64.1a20:  *00007ffcc3480000-00007ffcc3480fff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1a64.1a20:   00007ffcc3481000-00007ffcc35acfff 0x0020/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1a64.1a20:   00007ffcc35ad000-00007ffcc35b2fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1a64.1a20:   00007ffcc35b3000-00007ffcc35bffff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1a64.1a20:   00007ffcc35c0000-00007ffcc35c0fff 0x0004/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1a64.1a20:   00007ffcc35c1000-00007ffcc35c3fff 0x0008/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1a64.1a20:   00007ffcc35c4000-00007ffcc35c4fff 0x0010/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1a64.1a20:   00007ffcc35c5000-00007ffcc362bfff 0x0002/0x0080 0x1000000  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
1a64.1a20:   00007ffcc362c000-00007ff986c77fff 0x0001/0x0000 0x0000000
1a64.1a20:  *00007ffffffe0000-00007ffffffcffff 0x0001/0x0002 0x0020000
1a64.1a20: VBoxHeadless.exe: timestamp 0x555369a5 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
1a64.1a20: '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\Virtualbox\VBoxHeadless.exe' has no imports
1a64.1a20: '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll' has no imports
1a64.1a20: supR3HardNtChildPurify: Done after 320 ms and 0 fixes (loop #0).
1410.1a88: Log file opened: 4.3.28r100309 g_hStartupLog=0000000000000008 g_uNtVerCombined=0x63258000
1410.1a88: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: uNtDllAddr=00007ffcc3480000
1410.1a88: ntdll.dll: timestamp 0x550f4336 (rc=VINF_SUCCESS)
1410.1a88: New simple heap: #1 0000000000ce0000 LB 0x400000 (for 1753088 allocation)
1a64.1a20: supR3HardNtEnableThreadCreation:
1410.1a88: System32:  \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32
1410.1a88: WinSxS:    \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\WinSxS
1410.1a88: KnownDllPath: C:\Windows\system32
1410.1a88: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Opening vboxdrv stub...
1410.1a88: Error opening VBoxDrvStub:  STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
1410.1a88: supR3HardenedWinReadErrorInfoDevice: NtCreateFile -> 0xc0000034
1410.1a88: Error -101 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=3)
1410.1a88: NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND (0 retries)

Driver is probably stuck stopping/starting. Try 'sc.exe query vboxdrv' to get more information about its state. Rebooting may actually help.
1a64.1a20: supR3HardenedWinCheckChild: enmRequest=2 rc=-101 enmWhat=3 supR3HardenedWinReSpawn: NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND (0 retries)

Driver is probably stuck stopping/starting. Try 'sc.exe query vboxdrv' to get more information about its state. Rebooting may actually help.
1a64.1a20: Error -101 in supR3HardenedWinReSpawn! (enmWhat=3)
1a64.1a20: NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: 0xc0000034 STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND (0 retries)

Driver is probably stuck stopping/starting. Try 'sc.exe query vboxdrv' to get more information about its state. Rebooting may actually help.
```

exit code 1(0x1). More details avaliable 
in :

Comment: experiencing the same...

Answer (score 1):

Try to run andy with wompatibility Windows 7. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I found that quite often you need to start VMware Workstation XX Player manually and see if it shows any messages. Then try to lunch your Andy VM from \Users\.username\AppData\Roaming\Andy\machines\19e07117-....-....-....-490e37d9b6ff\images) using VMW Player and then start Andy Console. And wualya it working again ("Ф")

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling VirtualBox (NOT andy), re-downloading VirtualBox from  [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), and re-installing VirtualBox did the trick for me.